# Prove that $n\left(n(n-3)+8\right)$ is divisible by 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

The following expression seems to result in an integer for all $n$:
$$\frac13n\left(n(n-3)+8\right)$$
So, how do I prove that, if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, $n(n-3)+8$ is.

Comment: Note that if $n$ isn't a multiple of $3$, then it is either $1$ or $2$ mod $3$. Either way $n\cdot(n-3)$ is $1$ mod 3 since $n\cdot(n-3)$ mod $3=n^2\mod 3=1$. And, $1+8=9$.

Comment: Huh???!?  Try $n=3$.

Comment: The question body has the expression multiplied by $n$, which the title does not

Comment: $$n(n-3)+8=n^2-3n+9-1=n^2-1+9-3n=(n+1)(n-1)+3(3-n)$$ If $n$ is not divisible by $3$ then either $n+1$ or $n-1$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: It $\,= (n^3-n)/3 + 3n-n^2\,$ so it suffices to prove $\,3\mid n^3-n\,$ a much more well-known form, for which see the dupe for many methods (which subsume the answers below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac13n\left(n(n-3)+8\right)=\frac13n\left(n^2-3n+8\right)\\=\frac13n\left(n^2-3n+2+6\right)=\frac13n\left((n-1)(n-2)+6\right)\\=\frac13n(n-1)(n-2)+2$$
One of $n,\ n-1, \ n-2$ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **Mathematical Induction** to prove this.

**CASE 1 $(n=1)$:** So your equation turns out to be $$1(1(1-3)+8)=6=3(2)$$
Thus, when $n=1$, this equation is divisible by $3$.

**CASE 2 $(n=m)$:** We assume that $m(m(m-3)+8)$ is divisible by $3$.

**CASE 3 $(n=m+1)$:** The equation in this case becomes:
$$\begin{align}&(m+1)\{(m+1)(m+1-3)+8\}\\
=&(m+1)\{(m+1)(m-2)+8\}\\
=&(m+1)\left(m^2-m+6\right)\\
=&m^3+5m+6\\
=&\underbrace{m(m(m-3)+8)}_{\text{divisible by 3 from CASE 2}}+3\left(m^2-m+2\right)\\
\end{align}$$
Thus, the equation in **CASE 3** is also divisible by $3$.

Thus, by the **Principle of Mathematical Induction**, we can conclude that the equation $n(n(n-3)+8)$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$